# distinct count(*)

Tags: mysql

How to do get distinct count(*) in MySQL.

for example, in table1 i have 10 million record, there are duplicate records in it.

I want to find out distinct count(*) from the table.

I know, I can do

> select distinct * from table1
>   but, i don't want to fetch 10 million records, not even want to insert distinct records in other table like,
>   create table table2 select distinct * from table1

So, please help me with any other option.

Help from anyone welcome

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field) FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY field;
```

(btw - this has been answered quite a few times elsewhere on this site)

Answer (score 4):

Try using a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table1) T1
```

Comment: I have 10 million records in the table, so using subquery will slowdown the result

Comment: @Krunal: Are you *sure* it's slower?! What evidence do you have for that? Did you even *try* it?

Comment: I have tried. It took 1.30 min to get distinct records from 11256 rows. And I have 10 million records  in the table.

Comment: @Krunal: Is that a slowdown? How much faster is it if you use one of the other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM tab GROUP BY some_value )
```