# count rows but not with the same id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this table patients

`patient_id | job`

```
  2          nurse
  2          carpenter
  1          programmer
```

It should count 2 because it didnt include the same id

does anyone know a query for that? I'm using laravel

and this is my code so far

```
App\Notification::select('patients.*',DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
```

Comment: look into distinct keyword

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM patients GROUP BY job

Comment: Possible duplicate of [distinct count(\*)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887214/distinct-count)

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651727/laravel-eloquent-distinct-and-count-not-working-properly-together

Answer (score 1):

```
App\Notification::distinct('patient_id')->count();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT patient_id) FROM table_name;
```

that should work ... sorry ... had them backwards before

Answer (score 0):

Using Eloquent, you can do something like this:

```
$noti = \App\Notification::groupBy('patient_id')->get();
$count = $noti->count();
```